# Phonegap for windows phone 8, on a windows 8.1 preview

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8

I need to make an app on phone gap for windows phone 8, my PC has windows 8.1 pro preview. What version if visual studio is compatible with my situation and is available in trial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio 2013 available [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/).

Comment: Geez! I never knew that! --"
(No offense)

Comment: Dude if you knew that...What more do you want to know!